# Beginner urn probability question

Tags: probability, polya-urn-model

I am having issues getting my head around an urn problem.

I have seven urns. First three urns contain 4 balls (1 red, 3 blue) and the last 4 urns contain 3 balls (1 red, 2 blue).

If picking totally randomly one ball from each urn. What are the odds of

1. picking all red balls
2. picking all blue balls

---

What I thought would be the correct way to calculate the all red balls was

0.25 x 0.25 x 0.25 x 0.33 x 0.33 x 0.33 x 0.33

but that answer seems wrong.

I've been trying to find a solution or explanation online but so far have not been able to. Does anyone know of any good resource to learn this from or can explain it a bit better please.

Comment: Why does it seem wrong?

Comment: Because then the answer would be 0.0001... which seems such a low probability. Almost impossible.

Comment: @ogramp that does not mean that the answer is wrong. That just means that the answer is improbable :)

Comment: @AniruddhaDeb: or, more accurately, that the probability of success is low

Comment: Alright, I was sure I was mistaken because it is intro example problem and I was sure the answer is supposed to be simple. Thank you.

Comment: 0.0001853... is a number. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 7 independent experiments, i.e. $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = P(A_1)P(A_2)$, where $A_1, A_2$ are two experiments (i.e. two different urns), so you can multiply probabilities of success for each experiment.